I need a word the means “Bringer of a new world/ new things.”
I'm writing a story and I used the word messiah. I want to draw no parallels to scripture or the Bible. The character is a part of a prophecy that brings change to my world. He isn’t the main character but he is a crucial role in my story.
So I need a word that means “Bringer of a new world/ new things.”

Visionary reformist ?

Single word requests should be accompanied by a meaningful sentence that demonstrates how you will use the word.
